# Stop automatic newsletter subscription

Tags: magento, subscription, newsletter

I had to take over a shop (1.9.0.1) which was programatically a mess and was cleaning it up in the last weeks. 
Now there is still an issue I can not solve. Users get automatically assigned to the newsletter. Not only at the checkout (Checkbox has no effect), but also if somebody requests a new password and is not assigned to the newsletter yet. In the admin, I set Newsletter for double-opt-in, so the users get not a confirmed signup but a mail with the opt-in link.
I have mailchimp installed but heavily doubt that this has something to do with the issue. Rather than that I have no extension related to newsletter installed.
My luckiest guess is that somewhere there is an observer or handler that triggers it, but I have no idea where I can find it. Eventually even coded in the core files?
I am open for any ideas.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can check custom observer code in local or community code pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for events related to Subscriber model, to see if there is any observer for it.

Search for `newsletter_subscriber_*` (if I recall correctly) to see if there is an observer for its events.